# How to retrieve user's input label of drop down list in rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, form-helpers

The following simple form takes user input with a drop down list of `zone`. The `zone_id` of user input could be retrieved with `params[:controller][:zone_id]`.

```
<%=f.input :zone_id, :label => t('Zone'), :collection => Zone.where(:active => true).order('ranking_order'), :label_method => :zone_name, :value_method => :id, :include_blank => true %>
```

In our rails 3.2 app however, we also need to retain the label of user's input which is `zone_name` here. Is there a way to retrieve label (`zone_name`) of user's input in controller? Thanks.

Comment: Please paste your whole form_code here.

Comment: It seems you don't want it to be a simple dropdown list anymore. You want it to be a autocomplete text box, is that right?

Comment: It is a simple drop down list. In addition to the value stored in params[:controller][:zone_id], we want to retrieve the label as well in controller.